# Memcache for php5.5.0

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I've upgraded php for 5.5.0 and i cant find php_memcache.dll, maybe someone have some link?
[pecl4win.php.net](http://pecl4win.php.net) is down and there are no match in http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find memcache builds in the [Windows PECL downloads folder](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/). The newest version 3.0.7 also includes builds for PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

I try this but I got php5 is stop or missing error. It's because I download the wrong version.

The bold in indicate the php version I think. I use it for 32 bit windows.

php_memcache-3.0.8-**5.5**-ts-vc11-x86.zip

32 bit
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip

64 bit
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip